# Using `\scalebox` within drop cap

Tags: lettrine, scalebox

I am using `lettrine` for creating drop caps.

If a use the `\scalebox`-command within the first argument of `\lettrine` an error occurs. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{A}{} This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a 
simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a 
simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a 
simple test. This is a simple test.

A\scalebox{.5}{A}

\lettrine{A\scalebox{.5}{A}}{} This is a simple test. This is a simple 
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple 
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple 
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test.
\end{document}
```

I had no problem before, when Is used TeXLive 2017. Now with TeXLive 2018 the error occurs.

I use `lettrine` 2018-08-28 v2.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just protect `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[nindent=0.33em]{A}{} This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a
simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a
simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a
simple test. This is a simple test.

A\scalebox{.5}{A}\medskip

\lettrine[nindent=0.33em]{A\protect\scalebox{.5}{A}}{This} is a simple test. This is a simple
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test. This is a simple
test. This is a simple test. This is a simple test.

\end{document}
```

[image]